# Converting pdf to image - prevent text output

Tags: ghostscript

I know Ghostscript can translate pdf into png.

Can you tell which lines in the source code to comment out so that blocks with text are simply skipped (ignored) when converting pdf to png.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't modify the source. Instead use `-dFILTERTEXT` which will drop text rather than rendering it. See [here](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.23/Use.htm)